# Deleting particular column from a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
var array = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
            ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
            ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]]
```

How can I delete the second column in this array?

Comment: what is the "second column"? Alle the `b` values?

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify the index and then iterate over the array and splice the inner arrays.

```js
var array = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]],
    index = 1;

array.forEach(a => a.splice(index, 1));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```